# Swift Login with Apple fail after removing application

Tags: ios, swift, apple-login

I have issue. I have **AppleLogin** button with following action (see below). The logic what I did are:

- When user signing in for first time, its save his user object and uses it on next login try.

But I am getting fail, when I remove my app from device and trying install it again, on Apple login I am getting empty user credentials. It fixes only If I remove app from apps that using AppleID from device Settings. How I can handle this?

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
@objc func handleLogInWithAppleID() {
    let request = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider().createRequest()
    request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]
    
    let controller = ASAuthorizationController(authorizationRequests: [request])
    
    controller.delegate = self
    controller.presentationContextProvider = self
    controller.performRequests()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found issue by myself, I was saving credentials to RealmDB, not to Keychain :(

P.S hope this post helps to someone